# Multilingual site: what is the best way to store translations?

Tags: database, arrays, multilingual

Is it more efficient to store translated text in a database or inside a file using an array?

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242547/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-multiple-language-versions-of-a-website help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on what you're usign to develop, some Frameworks have localization functions, you should check if first. After that, if none is provided, database is a little bit complicated, imagine queries at every word. Id use some sort of INI file, if no localization functions are provided, or you could always check for some localization libraries. But since i don't know what language you're using to develop, there's no much i can do to help. If you want any help to find a library, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on your app. For massive CMS I would store it in a DB. For a small iOS app I would use a file that you read into an array.